# How do I find out what country did an email originate from?

Tags: email, ip

Out of curiosity I came across some emails in my inbox that I really wanted to know where they where sent from. Not just Google's or Yahoo's service's address, but the actual country the sender was in when the email went through. Is there a way of doing this? All the tools online I use are pointing me to company's facilities (usually somewhere in the USA).

Comment: If it is not in the email header info, then you can't find it.